# Access results from google places api ios for auto completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, google-places-api

I am using this method to get suggestions and i need to show them in tableview:

```
- (void)placeAutocomplete:(NSString *)autoCompleteString {
    [self.autoCompleteSuggestionsList removeAllObjects];
    GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
    filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity;

    [_placesClient autocompleteQuery:(NSString *)autoCompleteString
                              bounds:nil
                              filter:filter
                            callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                                if (error != nil) {
                                    NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                    return;
                                }

                                for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results) {
                                    //NSLog(@"Result '%@' with placeID %@", result.attributedFullText.string, result.placeID);
                                    //NSRange autoCompleteRange = [result.attributedFullText.string rangeOfString:autoCompleteString];
                                    //if (autoCompleteRange.location == 0) {
                                    //NSString *stringNow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",result.attributedFullText.string];
                                    [self.autoCompleteSuggestionsList addObject:result.attributedFullText.string];
                                        //NSLog(@"test : %@",stringNow);
                                    //NSLog(@"%@",self.autoCompleteSuggestionsList);
                                    //}
                                }
                            }];
    [self.autocompleteTableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.autoCompleteSuggestionsList);
}
```

but I cannot access the results outside of the autocompleteQuery method

when logged it shows correctly inside the method but not outside ,
I am using mutable array to access it but i shows correctly inside but not outside.

I don't need suggestions for using any third party autocomplete pod .
I am getting the result i just need them to be accessed from the method so that it could be accessible to show the tableview as well

Comment: reload table inside autoComplete block.(After completing for loop)

Comment: thanks buddy thank you very much:

Comment: thanks thank you , please post this as an answer for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reload the data inside the block.

> Reason for doing this is simple because block is run in different thread so when it complete the execution it come in callback block with main thread thats why we need to reload table in block.

```
- (void)placeAutocomplete:(NSString *)autoCompleteString {
    [self.autoCompleteSuggestionsList removeAllObjects];
    GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
    filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity;

    [_placesClient autocompleteQuery:(NSString *)autoCompleteString
                              bounds:nil
                              filter:filter
                            callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                                if (error != nil) {
                                    NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                    return;
                                }

                                for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results) {

                                    [self.autoCompleteSuggestionsList addObject:result.attributedFullText.string];

                                }
                                [self.autocompleteTableView reloadData];
                            }];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.autoCompleteSuggestionsList);
}
```

Comment: Happy coding @Saurabh