# Google Places iOS - Autocomplete Filter

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I got this error when using `autocompleteQuery:bounds:filter:callback:`

> Autocomplete error -3 The operation couldn’t be completed. An internal
>   error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error
>   represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our
>   community and support page
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/support).

Full error: `NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", error);`

> Autocomplete error Error Domain=com.google.places.ErrorDomain Code=-3
>   "An internal error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe
>   this error represents a bug, please file a report using the
>   instructions on our community and support page
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/support)."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An internal error occurred in the
>   Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please
>   file a report using the instructions on our community and support page
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/support).,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x600000851c40 {Error
>   Domain=com.google.places.server.ErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000008521e0 {Error
>   Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=403 "Forbidden"
>   UserInfo={GTLRStructuredError=GMSx_GTLRErrorObject 0x600000852180:
>   {message:"Forbidden" errors:[1] code:403},
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Forbidden}}}}}

Appdelegate.m

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"API_KEY"]; //for google maps
[GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:@"API_KEY_FOR_GPlaces"];
```

ObjectFile.m

```
- (void)placeAutocompleteFilterWithQuery:(NSString *)query countryCode:(NSString *)country andAutocompleteType:(GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter)type withCallBack:(void (^)(NSArray<GMSAutocompletePrediction *> * results, NSError * error))autoCompleteResults{

    if (query.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
    filter.type = type;
    filter.country = country;

    GMSPlacesClient *placesClient = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];
    [placesClient autocompleteQuery:query bounds:nil filter:filter callback:^(NSArray<GMSAutocompletePrediction *> * _Nullable results, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %ld %@", error.code, [error localizedDescription]);
            autoCompleteResults(nil, error);
            return;
        }

        for (GMSAutocompletePrediction *prediction in results) {
            NSLog(@"attributedFullText: %@", prediction.attributedFullText);
            NSLog(@"types: %@", prediction.types);
            NSLog(@"----------------------");
        }
        autoCompleteResults(results, nil);

    }];
}
```

Yesterday.
I start the code and try using this from yesterday morning, it works until reach the limit usage (get error.code -3 `kGMSPlacesInternalError`, not -6 for `kGMSPlacesUsageLimitExceeded`).

Today.
Today I try again (hope I can use this), only 2 success requests then get the same error.

Comment: I hope that below Answer is helpfull to you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32796759